# Database resource: amount of different operating systems across the years

Tags: data-request, computing, technology

I would like to perform data analysis of the amount of machines using different operating systems (Windows, Mac,Linux Android, etc.) across the years. Any idea where I could get the data?

**UPDATE**

I am specifically interested in the absolute value of devices since e.q. 1980. The total number of devices will grow so it would be nice to also include that information. Also (if possible), devices should distinguish between laptops, smartphones, tablets, workstations etc.

Answer (score 3):

Going back to 2009, Statcounter has timeseries data and custom filters and geographical regions. Resolution goes down to "daily".

http://gs.statcounter.com/os-market-share#monthly-200901-201805

Click *Download Data (.csv)* to get the raw data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @philshem! The y-axis data is in percent. It would nice to see how many devices are actually out there. Windows might be 'dying' in statistics if smartphone market grows rapidly. Also, it would be very interesting to see how the trends had changed since e.g. 1980.

Comment: @WoofDoggy please update your question if you have specific requirements (absolute instead of relative market share, and also going back farther)